# Redundant Binary Upload. There already a binary upload with build version'1' for train '1.1.2" at Softwareassets

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting error "Redundant Binary Upload. There already a binary upload with build version'1' for train '1.1.2" at Softwareassets" when trying upload an updated version to appStore.
[image]

However, I already incremented "build" version number. as shown below:
[image]

Moreover, I notice, one issue, even though I changed build and version numbers, but still Xcode display the old version number when display the error and also in the details under organizer windows:

[image]

Notice, actually my app version and build numbers are 1.2 and 1.2.1 respectively on General settings.

I dont know why xcode doesn't realize that version and build numbers have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I asked the wrong question. I'm getting this error because I forgot to archive the project first before uploading to Appstore. 
The reason I didn't archive because archive was giving an error which I posted as as another question at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this will help, becoz even I had faced many unpredicted issues while submitting the apps recently.

But for the basics,

1. if app is not reviewed yet:

> Your Version number must be same as It is there in itunesConnect Account,
>     and you can update the new build with updating only build number

2. And if your is reviewed or published:

> you need to update both version and build numbers

Also, if possible once try to submit the build from xcode and submit the app from itunesConnect.

Hope this will help,
Thanks.

Comment: Then Wait for 6 hrs and try again, hope it will work,